# find difference of two objects in height and assign height to another object

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

find difference of two objects in height and assign height to another object using jquery or javascript. Actually objects(container/section) have dynamic content, so these objects are dynamic in height. So, I want to find difference of two objects and then assign this difference to another object.
For example
Div3(size in height) = Div1(size in height)-Div2(size in height).

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): _"Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the `id` of the divs are `div1`, `div2` and `div3`. 
Then using JQuery `.height()` function.

```
$("#div3").height($("#div1").height() - $("#div2").height());
```

You can use either `.height()` or `.innerHeight()` or `.outerHeight()`. (See here for the [difference between the three](http://www.texelate.co.uk/blog/post/91-jquery-whats-the-difference-between-height-innerheight-and-outerheight/))

```js
var diff = $("#div1").height() - $("#div2").height();
$("#div3").height(diff);
$("#div4").css("margin-top", diff);
```

```css
#div1 {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}

#div2 {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#div3 {
  background-color: green;
}

#div4 {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
<div id="div4"></div>
```

Comment: This can produce a negative difference/height which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: yes, its working fine, Rithwik can we use this difference as margin-top for Div4 ?

Comment: @BilluG Yes. You can use it for any attribute. Use : `$("#div4").css("margin-top", diff);`. I have updated the snippet also.